# bread dough rising without airing cupboard

Tags: baking

I did live in a house with an airing cupboard which did work.  However, I have a breadmaker and make the dough ready to shape into pitta bread pieces but how do I make it rise as I don’t have an airing cupboard.

Comment: Welcome to the site! What is your question? At the moment it isn't clear, and is likely  to be closed.

Comment: Welcome! You may want to take the [tour] and browse through our [help], especially [ask], then [edit] your post to have a clear question. It may also be a good idea to search the existing questions, we do have some on raising dough.

Comment: Anne, could you check: does [this Q/A](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-do-you-raise-your-dough-in-cold-seasons) answer your question?

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10310/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2276/67

Answer (score 2):

Use your oven. If you wish, turn the oven on at its lowest temperature for about 10 minutes **before** you want to rise your dough. Then turn it off and place your dough inside.

Another trick is to add a pan of warm water to the bottom of your oven while the dough rises -- this increases the humidity which may help with rising.

Comment: Or turn the oven light on and close the door.